# 3D Scatter Plot with Colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-3d

Borrowing from the [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) on the Matplotlib documentation page and slightly modifying the code,

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zl, zh)
    cs = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=cs, marker=m)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Will give a 3D scatter plot with different colors for each point (random colors in this example). What's the correct way to add a colorbar to the figure, since adding in `plt.colorbar()` or `ax.colorbar()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is `cs` in your example?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This produces a colorbar (though possibly not the one you need):

Replace this line:

```
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=cs, marker=m)
```

with

```
p = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=cs, marker=m)
```

then use

```
fig.colorbar(p)
```

near the end

Answer (score 11):

Using the above answer did not solve my problem. The colorbar colormap was not linked to the axes (note also the incorrect colorbar limits):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = np.random.rand(3, 100)
x, y, z = data  # for show
c = np.arange(len(x)) / len(x)  # create some colours

p = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=plt.cm.magma(0.5*c))
ax.set_xlabel('$\psi_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$\Phi$')
ax.set_zlabel('$\psi_2$')

ax.set_box_aspect([np.ptp(i) for i in data])  # equal aspect ratio

fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
```

[image: bad example]

The solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075179/12063126) also) is to use `cmap` in `ax.scatter`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = np.random.rand(3, 100)
x, y, z = data  # for show
c = np.arange(len(x)) / len(x)  # create some colours

p = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=0.5*c, cmap=plt.cm.magma)
ax.set_xlabel('$\psi_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$\Phi$')
ax.set_zlabel('$\psi_2$')

ax.set_box_aspect([np.ptp(i) for i in data])  # equal aspect ratio

fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: You passed the values `c` (which ranges from 0. to 1.) through the cm.magma function, which altered all the values, and gave the impression of an incorrect range.  I would not say that my answer was incorrect, but that your first attempt to change the colormap was incorrect.  Your second answer correctly sets the colormap with the `cmap` argument.

Comment: why is 0.5*c needed?

Comment: It is not needed, but `c` is bounded `[0..1]` and `0.5` was added as a scaling factor to show that the scale bar displays appropriate units in the second plot, which is not the case in the first plot.